# Netbeans 12.x, 13 and datasource problems

Tags: netbeans, datasource, wizard

Netbeans 12.x and 13 on windows, entity classes from database wizard. Sometimes the wizard stop working, I cannot connect to database with the configured datasorce or the datasorce selection box is disabled. Loading a different project the wizard works again but once it is broken on a certain project it is very hard to restore it. In the past incidents I solved moving to the latest release of Netbeans, but this time is not an option, I'm with the latest.

Some data is corrupted but I don't know how to clean and start again. On windows Netbeans stores its data in the folder **appdata/local** and **appdata/roaming**, but I think the corrupted data is not there, it is project related. In the project folder I cannot find any info about the datasource it uses.

Am I missing something ?

Should I try to delete netbeans folder inside **appdata/local** and **appdata/roaming** ?

**UPDATE 1**

Today is my lucky day and the wizard suddenly started working again, so no chances to get IDE log. I remember a null pointer exception launching the wizard, but nothing about the stack trace. The project is a web application which connectes to a mysql db. I'm sure I have tried both Netbeans restart and computer restart to restore the wizard and it was useless. Now it works again but I cannot explain why...and I'm sure I will have problems again in the future. The Jdbc driver I use is quite old (mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar) but don't think it is the source of the problem.

Comment: [1] Update your question with any information written to the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**). [2] Before deleting anything, perhaps try to create a trivial new project that attempts to replicate the problem, and update your question accordingly. [3] If that works then consider deleting your cache directory only (presumably **appdata/local**?). No need to delete your user directory if deleting the cache directory fixes the problem. [4] If nothing else works consider deleting your user directory as well (presumably **appdata/roaming**?), though you may lose unrelated information by doing that.

Comment: Also, as it stands, your question is a little vague, and it needs to be more specific. Can you add more details (DB? Java version? Project type? Precise error message with a screen shot, are the problem(s) reproducible?... etc.)